# images not showing up when webpage published

Tags: html

So I seem to be having a strange problem. When I open up my HTML pages locally, everything shows up and everything works. However, once I uploaded them to the server for my website only two of the images show up.

All of my images are in the same folder as all of my HTML pages and there are still a few images that work. Is this an issue with my image paths? Or is it something with my host since some of the images will load?

Here is the URL for my webpage: clepert.jomc-class.org

Comment: Thanks for all of the help, I believe my problem is a syntax error, my images are on the server with .JPG when it's searching for .jpg.

Comment: So what your saying is... my answer was correct? " http://clepert.jomc-class.org/bckgrnd.jpg So I would check for this file specifically on your server." Anyways this question should now be closed as "off topic".

Answer (score 0):

Must be a problem with images path since there a not on the server at the path that you wrote.
Maybe you didn't put them on the server or there has been a problem during the transfer. Check if they are on the server.

Comment: Yeah, I changed some pages to fix some minor things and uploaded them again but they haven't changed at all yet. According to my FTP client everything is there. I've used both FileZilla and Cyberduck and both show that all of my files are there. There is obviously a slight delay with the hosting service but I uploaded all of the pictures almost 24 hours ago.

Comment: I just checked out your website at this moment, all images are here, did you do anything ? If not there is obviously a delay between the upload on the FTP and the effective change on the web, maybe an ethic check from your hosting service (like you do not have the right to upload pornography on some hosting services and they check your pages before putting online, like your FTP that you're working with is different from the one that's used for real because they need to check that)

Answer (score 0):

**Just because the browser gets a 404 back doesn't mean the file isn't there.**  It might be that the user / server doesn't have permission to access the file (not everyone uses the 401 status code).

1. Check the logs!  They will save you LOTS of time.
2. Check the permissions of the directory and all other files you're
   trying to access.
3. Make sure your paths are correct (local vs absolute, etc).
4. Post more details if that doesn't help.
5. Check the logs again.

Answer (score 0):

I got this for your background: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). http://clepert.jomc-class.org/bckgrnd.jpg 
So I would check for this file specifically on your server.

Otherwise your logo is a white image on a white background... so it won't show without a colored background.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve such things is to check the browsers Developer-Tools and take a look at the console or network section (different from browser to browser).

[image]

You're getting an 404-Error so maybe the path is wrong, or the image is just not on your server.

Comment: Right now the path for my background image is this:

    `background-image: url(bckgrnd.jpg);`

My images all follow this format:

    `<img src="mark1.jpg" width="420" alt="Man conducting small  musical ensemble.">`

Even the images that do work have that same format. Should I maybe consider changing the path to:

    `<img src="www/mark1.jpg">`